# Limit users to join in Agora with Flutter

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I have created video calling app with agora_uikit now I want to make sure that 8 users can join in video call.

Is there anyone has solution for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.